# Will ASP.NET Page Life Cycle run full course when connection was closed unexpectedly?

Tags: asp.net, connection, page-lifecycle

Will Asp.net run its full page life cycle although the remote connection was closed unexpectedly to a state that stream data cannot be send the client?  It is a blank asp.net page with default values. and I am concern about OnUnLoad event not being executed. Will it actually happen?

Anyone got any detail info on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should design your pages in a way that does not rely on that event execution.

The web/network is unpredictable, anything can always happen, browser crash, bug, connection is lost or slow or works and doesn't then works again...

I am convinced that when you close the browser the web request is disposed but since you ask about the web form page life cycle, it concludes with the `Page_PreRender` then the data is sent to the client, there are so many variables and possibilities that I think is safer to always imagine the whole life cycle will get executed even if there will be nobody to use/consume the response.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a guess, but I think that client disconnection somehow raises a `ThreadAbortException`. Hence, any of the next events will not occur any more. You can, of course, try to catch the exception and then free up your resources.